# Ubuntu 19.10 - how to install JavaFX with java 8

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, ubuntu-19.04

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~19.10-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

However, the openjfx package:

```
sudo apt list openjfx
Listing... Gotowe
openjfx/eoan,now 11.0.2+1-1 amd64 [installed]
openjfx/eoan 11.0.2+1-1 i386
```

seems to be compiled with java 10, as I cannot run any JavaFX applications:

```
Error:(3, 26) java: cannot access javafx.application.Application
  bad class file: /usr/share/openjfx/lib/javafx.graphics.jar!/javafx/application/Application.class
    class file has wrong version 54.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

Has anymode made it work?

Comment: use the oracle version that also includes javafx

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX/OpenJFX is not a part of OpenJDK lately, so you either to install it separately, or use OpenJDK builds with prepackaged OpenJFX.

Comment: e.g. https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?&version=java-8-lts&architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx